# how do we paginate activity feed from getStream.io in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, getstream-io

I'm new to getStream.io and i'm retrieving feed from flatfeed don't know how to paginate response in flutter.I know we pass offset and limit but how could I know to change offset value dynamically.

Comment: If this is a ranked feed, then you need to use the last `score` value to pass it to the `score_lt` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Paginated methods such as `flatFeed.getPaginatedEnrichedActivities` return a json response with a field "next". This field is something of this order:

"/api/v1.0/enrich/feed/user/sacha/?api_key=$keyField&id_lt=$idLtField&limit=$limitField"

Essentially you need to parse the URL parameters `limit` and `id_lt` in order to query the next page and so on until "next" is null.

We have simplified this process in the core package with `loadMoreEnrichedActivities`. In the [tutorial](https://getstream.io/activity-feeds/sdk/flutter/tutorial/#posting-activities---compose-activity-page) there is an **Activities Pagination** section where you can read more about it